# Ubuntu partition "unallocated" and Win7 BSODs

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I've successfully used Boot Repair to get out of booting binds in the past, but this time I'm stuck and was directed by Boot Repair to share the following web address in a trusted forum such as this: http://paste2.org/IZVKL8Uz (this shows details of what Boot Repair did and found on my system)

In case some additional information might be helpful, the problem arose after Windows crashed and did some kind of registry defragmentation when restarted. That led to multiple BSODs with error messages like this:

> problem detected and windows shut down to prevent damage
>   win32k.sys
>   PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
>   make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed...if problems continue, disable or remove newly installed hardware or software...disable BIOS memory options (but there was no newly installed hardware or software that I'm aware of)

That was followed by the following error message

> error: no such partition
>   grub rescue>

Using Boot Repair, I got back to the BSOD and the associated error messages listed above, but now I'm stuck there again.

Using GParted, I see that where my Ubuntu partition should be there now seems to be only "unallocated" space.

Any ideas about what's happened and what I might try? Thanks. --Brian

Comment: Should I go nuclear and reinstall Ubuntu--and GRUB along with it--since that Ubuntu partition seems empty now?